# Getting unusual fradulent advertisment notifications as popup

Tags: firefox, notification

I am getting such notifications repeatedly as Notifications popups and in Notification List. Clicking them opens a not-official looking webpage with some IP address url. For example: `http://198.251.89.173/5.php`

<del>I have a slight assumption that they are being sent via Firefox.</del>Notifs only popup when Firefox is running. It is also the only browser on my system.

I know popups can be turned off but I don't understand how did these get permissions to send notifs. I want to remove the root cause and also don't want any data losses or theft on my system.
OS : Ubuntu 18.04

[image: Notification claiming to from PhonePe]

[image: Notification claiming to from Google Pay]

They are being sent almost every 10 seconds. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out someone had accidently pressed "Allow" for push notifications on a fraudulent site.

I changed notification permissions in Preferences and blocked few websites.